# Filling in missing glyphs in fonts with fontforge

Tags: unicode, fonts, truetype, opentype, fontforge

### Background

I'm trying to convert the [Google Noto Sans JP](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-jpan) font from a `.otf` to a `.ttf`, using the following fontforge script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env fontforge

Open($1)
CIDFlatten()
Generate($1:r + ".ttf")
Close()
```

When I call `Open` on the `.otf`, I get a load of errors saying that there are lots of missing glyphs:

```
No glyph with unicode U+07d22 in font
No glyph with unicode U+07d2f in font
No glyph with unicode U+07da0 in font
...
```

My script converts the `.otf` into a `.ttf` but, sure enough, when I load the font these characters aren't rendered (they look like this: `[X]`).

So I'd like to *fill in the gaps* and copy identical glyphs into the missing slots.

### The Problem

So I run the following script to try and substitute one of the missing glyphs ([U+7d22](https://codepoints.net/U+7d22)) with an identical one ([U+f96a](https://codepoints.net/U+F96A)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env fontforge

Open($1)
CIDFlatten()

Select(0uf96a)
Copy()
Select(0u7d22)
Paste()
SelectNone()

Generate($1:r + ".ttf")
Close()
```

However fontforge fails to select the non-existent character U+7d22:

```
Select: Character not found: U+7D22
```

Does anyone know how to copy a glyph to a codepoint that doesn't have a glyph?

Or in other words, does anyone know how to fill the gaps in this font?

Comment: Hang on, back up. **why** are you converting from `otf` to `ttf`? (the font will blow up in size, and all glyph outlines will get lossy-converted from cubic Bezier to quadratic Bezier form)

Comment: Just because the program I want to use the font in supports `ttf` and not `otf` - I don't really mind about the losses involved when going backwards to a less advanced format.

Comment: That leaves the question "which program?" because both ttf and otf are OpenType fonts, so programs that support OpenType fonts with a ttf extension but not with an otf extension are worth explaining as part of your "this is what I need it for" problem statement.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans This is a useful question without such context. I need such a question answered for Magento 2: PHP Zend_Pdf, which is supported in Magento 2.3 doesn't implement a Japanese, Korean or Chinese charset, meaning that this font trickery is required as good free .ttf asian charsets are thin on the ground

Comment: No, you don't: PDF, adobe's format, very much supports otf, Adobe's preferred format. In fact, it supports every OpenType flavour, becuase ttf and otf are both just opentype fonts. And there are plenty of good free opentpye CJK fonts out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out you can "fill in the gaps" in `ttf` format, so I first converted the font, then copied the glyphs, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env fontforge

Open($1)
CIDFlatten()
Generate($1:r + ".ttf")
Close()

Open($1:r + ".ttf")

Select(0uf96a)
Copy()
Select(0u7d22)
Paste()
SelectNone()

Generate($1:r + ".ttf")
Close()
```

Comment: Hey, this is all good, but how would I do this with the entire font?